# Is there a reciprocal function in Octave?

Tags: octave

Is there a built-in function in Octave to compute the element-wise reciprocal of a matrix, or is it necessary to implement a function that runs code like `mRecip = ones(size(m)) ./ m`?

A quick search through the documentation for "recip" or "reciprocal" didn't yield anything useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following seems to work just as well:

```
mRecip = 1./m
```